# Why is "get_rect()" not working for a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a collision hitbox for my sprites but when I try to use `get_rect` this error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

Does anyone know how to do this for a list of images?

```
scarn_up = [pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Up 1.png'), pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Up 2.png')]
scarn_up_rect = scarn_up.get_rect(topleft=(340, 150))
```

Comment: Because lists don't have that method. Not sure what you are expecting here. Perhaps you meant to call that method on all the objects in your list?

Comment: like `[s(topleft=(340, 150)) for s in scarn_up]`

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah that's what I meant

Comment: Something like: `scarn_up_rect = [x.get_rect(topleft=(340, 150)) for x in scarn_up]`?

Comment: Thank you so much Valentino! I think it might have worked

Answer (score 1):

Lists do not have a `get_rect` method. You want to do that on the `pygame.Surface` objects stored in your list. And you probably want to do it for each one of them and store their results in another list:

```
scarn_up = [pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Up 1.png'), pygame.image.load('Michael Scarn Up 2.png')]
scarn_up_rect = [x.get_rect(topleft=(340, 150)) for x in scarn_up]
```

Comment: Or get the `rect` individually - `scarn_up[0].get_rect(topleft=(340, 150))` and obviously for `scarn_up[1]`.